# How do I get the looping index when using Python zip-function?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

When simultaneously looping over multiple python lists, for which I use the `zip`-function, I also want to retrieve the looping index. To this end, a separate list for the looping index may be included in the zip-function, e.g.:

```
for index, item1, item2 in zip(range(len(list1)), list1, list2):
    <do something>
```

Is there a better way to do this (like in the `enumerate`-function)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can unpack everything in the `for`:

```
>>> for i, (x1, x2) in enumerate(zip([1,2,3], [3,4,5])):
...     print i, x1, x2
... 
0 1 3
1 2 4
2 3 5
```

Comment: ah, thanks, I didn't know that `enumerate` and `zip` could actually be combined to achieve just this!

Comment: @DSM, very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `enumerate()` for this (note the placement of parentheses after `for` to unpack the nested tuples):

```
>>> l1 = range(0, 10)
>>> l2 = range(10, 20)
>>> for index, (item1, item2) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)):
...   print index, item1, item2
... 
0 0 10
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
6 6 16
7 7 17
8 8 18
9 9 19
```

Comment: Thanks to you too, it's always reassuring to see different sources coming up with the same solution! :-)